# Artifactory web page is unaccessible

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory has been installed on a RHEL 6.2 machine using RPM, but I couldn't connect to the Artifactory webpage using the link `http://<server-ip>:8081/artifactory`

When I use `curl http://localhost:8081/artifactory` on the same machine, it doesnt show up any error.

Later in the day, realized, there is no Apache on this machine. So installed Apache on the yum repository and followed the instructions for [Running Behind HTTP Server](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Running+Behind+Apache+HTTPd) and configured the `httpd.conf` file under `/etc/httpd/conf` with below configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName <server-ip>
        ServerAlias <server-ip>
        ServerAdmin <email-address>

        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass /artifactory/ http://localhost:8081/artifactory/
        ProxyPassReverse /artifactory/ http://<server-ip>:8081/artifactory/

#       DocumentRoot /srv/www/httpd/htdocs/

        ErrorLog "logs/artifactory-error_log"
        #CustomLog
#       ServerSignature Off
```

But still couldn't connect to the Artifactory webpage. What does Document Root refer to, I do not have this directory on my machine.

Do I install Apache first before installing Artifactory or my installations should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets put aside the small things.
 1. You don't have to install apache to work with Artifactory, it should work just fine without it.
 2. DocumentRoot is a mandatory element but useless when Apache is used as a proxy for Tomcat, so it can point to any path (doesn't' have to actually exist).

Now, to the business. When you see a blank page instead of Artifactory home page, it usually means that something went wrong during the install. You should look in the logs (both `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs/artifactory.log` and Tomcat logs (`catalina.out` and `localhost.log`) in `/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/logs`. Chances are you'll be able to easily spot the error (ports conflict, permissions issue, etc.) if not, please update the question with the relevant log parts.